# SwiftUI.ViewBuilder - Generic parameter 'C0' could not be inferred

Tags: swift

When I add a **displayMode** to the **.navigationBarTitle** on a **VStack** I'm getting the compile error: `Generic parameter 'C0' could not be inferred`. If I remove the **displayMode** the code compiles.

This code works:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RecipeView: View {

    let recipe: RecipeViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(recipe.picture)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .cornerRadius(5)
            IngredientListView(ingredients: recipe.ingredients)
            DirectionListView(directions: recipe.directions)
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(recipe.name)
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RecipeView: View {

    let recipe: RecipeViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(recipe.picture)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .cornerRadius(5)
            IngredientListView(ingredients: recipe.ingredients)
            DirectionListView(directions: recipe.directions)
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(recipe.name, displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 12):

I upgraded to Xcode 11.4 with Swift 5.2 and got a slight different error `No exact matches in call to instance method 'navigationBarTitle(_:displayMode:)'`

On a whim I wrapped the `recipe.name` in a `Text()` like this

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text(recipe.name), displayMode: .inline)
```

and the issue resolved.